# Log4J JDBCAppender exception with MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, log4j

I use the following code to get a DB logger that uses log4j.

```
            PatternLayout layout = new PatternLayout();

            JDBCAppender jdbcAppender = new JDBCAppender();
            jdbcAppender.setDriver(jdbc);
            jdbcAppender.setUser(user);
            jdbcAppender.setPassword(password);
            jdbcAppender.setURL(url);
            jdbcAppender
                    .setSql("INSERT INTO " + logTable + " VALUES('%x', '%d', '%C', '%p', '%m')");
            jdbcAppender.setLayout(layout);
            jdbcAppender.activateOptions();

            Logger rootLogger = Logger.getRootLogger();
            rootLogger.setLevel(Level.DEBUG);
            rootLogger.addAppender(jdbcAppender);

            Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(type);
```

Logging throws exceptions:
`logger.info("This is log");`

```
log4j:ERROR Failed to excute sql
java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'is'.
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SQLDiagnostic.addDiagnostic(SQLDiagnostic.java:372)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.tdsErrorToken(TdsCore.java:2988)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.nextToken(TdsCore.java:2421)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.getMoreResults(TdsCore.java:671)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.processResults(JtdsStatement.java:613)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.executeSQL(JtdsStatement.java:572)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.executeImpl(JtdsStatement.java:809)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.executeUpdate(JtdsStatement.java:1288)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.executeUpdate(JtdsStatement.java:1241)
    at org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender.execute(JDBCAppender.java:218)
    at org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender.flushBuffer(JDBCAppender.java:289)
    at org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender.append(JDBCAppender.java:186)
    at org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton.doAppend(AppenderSkeleton.java:251)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:66)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:206)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:391)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.info(Category.java:666)
    at com.nirvasoft.logging.Main.main(Main.java:20)
```

What might be causing the error?

Comment: What is your `logTable`?

Comment: It's called `logs`. I created using `
SELECT TOP 1000 [USER_ID]
      ,[DATED]
      ,[LOGGER]
      ,[LEVEL]
      ,[MESSAGE]
  FROM [log_db].[dbo].[LOGS]`

Comment: Did you solved it ?